# Component variable in variables.scss doesn’t work

Tags: ionic4

I wrote the code below in the file of “variables.scss” or “global.scss”:

```
ion-searchbar {
–placeholder-color: white;
–placeholder-opacity:1;
–icon-color:white;
}
```

it should make the text of placeholder with white color, however, it doesn’t work.

But, if I write the code just in the page css file, it does work.

Does somebody know why?

Comment: I think your specific issue is that it should start with `--`. The `:root` tip is good for using in other component-level files, but the `variables.scss` and `global.scss` shouldn't have this `:root` requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it within the `:root` pseudo selector, like this:

```
:root {

  ion-searchbar {
    --placeholder-color: white;
    –-placeholder-opacity: 1;
    –-icon-color: white;
  }

}
```

This will ensure that any variables you set inside of :root will apply across your entire application.

Comment: I have another question, if I put these code outside of pseudo selector of :root, just I did, what and which parts of ion-searchbar component will be affected? Also if I put this code in the global.css, what component will be affected? Thanks!

Comment: I believe changing variables outside of :root within your variables.scss file will not affect your components. I also think the difference between variables.scss and global.scss is a matter of code organization. The variables.scss file is where you can override the default Ionic Variables. The global.scss file is where a lot of the core Ionic CSS is imported, and you can also use it as an entry point to import other CSS/Sass files to be included in the output CSS for your application.